# how do i avoid repeating data in my project

Tags: vb.net

The following is my code, I am doing project on online examination.when i click on next button the questions are repeated.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class Questions
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim Result As Integer = 0
    Dim Question_ID As Integer = Nothing
    Dim strconn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strconn)

    Protected Sub rblQuestion_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rblQuestion1.SelectedIndexChanged
        CheckAnswer(rblQuestion1.SelectedValue, lblQuestion1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckAnswer(ByVal Answer As String, ByVal Question As String)
        Dim RetrievedAnswer As String = Nothing

        Try
            Dim daQuestionID As New SqlDataAdapter("select Question_ID from tblQuestions where Question='" & Question & "'", con)
            Dim dsQuestionID As New Data.DataSet
            Dim dtQuestionID As New Data.DataTable

            If Not con.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()
            daQuestionID.Fill(dsQuestionID)
            dtQuestionID = dsQuestionID.Tables(0)

            If Not dtQuestionID.Rows.Count <= 0 Then
                If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestionID.Rows(0).Item("Question_ID")) Then
                    Question_ID = dtQuestionID.Rows(0).Item("Question_ID")

                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
             End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        Try
            Dim daAnswer As New SqlDataAdapter("select Answer from tblQuestions where Question_ID=" & Question_ID, con)
            Dim dsAnswer As New Data.DataSet
            Dim dtAnswer As New Data.DataTable

            If Not con.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()
            daAnswer.Fill(dsAnswer)
            dtAnswer = dsAnswer.Tables(0)

            If Not dtAnswer.Rows.Count <= 0 Then
                If Not IsDBNull(dtAnswer.Rows(0).Item("Answer")) Then
                    RetrievedAnswer = dtAnswer.Rows(0).Item("Answer")
                End If
            End If

            If RetrievedAnswer = Answer Then
                Try
                    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\\result.txt")
                    Result = sr.ReadLine
                    sr.Close()
                    Result = Result + 1
                    Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\\result.txt")
                    sw.WriteLine(Result)
                    sw.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Try
                Dim daQuestions As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 20 * FROM tblQuestions ORDER BY NEWID()", con)
                Dim dsQuestions As New Data.DataSet
                Dim dtQuestions As New Data.DataTable

                If Not con.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()
                daQuestions.Fill(dsQuestions)
                dtQuestions = dsQuestions.Tables(0)

                If Not dtQuestions.Rows.Count <= 0 Then
                    'For Question 1
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Question")) Then
                        lblQuestion1.Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Question")
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option1")) Then
                        rblQuestion1.Items(0).Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option1")
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option2")) Then
                        rblQuestion1.Items(1).Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option2")
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option3")) Then
                        rblQuestion1.Items(2).Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option3")
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option4")) Then
                        rblQuestion1.Items(3).Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option4")
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            'con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
            cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into tblQuestions (Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4,) values (@question, @option1, @option2, @option3, @option4)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", lblQuestion1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@option1", rblQuestion1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@option2", rblQuestion1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@option3", rblQuestion1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@option4", rblQuestion1.Text)
            'cmdInsertQuestion.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", txtAnswer.Text)
            Try
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
                MsgBox(" ")
                'txtAnswer.Text = ""
                rblQuestion1.Text = ""
                rblQuestion1.Text = ""
                rblQuestion1.Text = ""
                rblQuestion1.Text = ""
            Catch ex As Exception
                'ex.Message
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub       

    Protected Sub rblQuestion1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rblQuestion1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If IsPostBack Then
            Try
                Dim daQuestions As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 20 * FROM tblQuestions ORDER BY NEWID()", con)
                Dim dsQuestions As New Data.DataSet
                Dim dtQuestions As New Data.DataTable
                rblQuestion1.ClearSelection()
                If Not con.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()
                daQuestions.Fill(dsQuestions)
                dtQuestions = dsQuestions.Tables(0)

                If Not dtQuestions.Rows.Count <= 0 Then

                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Question")) Then
                        lblQuestion1.Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Question")
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option1")) Then
                        rblQuestion1.Items(0).Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option1")
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option2")) Then
                        rblQuestion1.Items(1).Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option2")
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option3")) Then
                        rblQuestion1.Items(2).Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option3")
                    End If
                    If Not IsDBNull(dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option4")) Then
                        rblQuestion1.Items(3).Text = dtQuestions.Rows(0).Item("Option4")
                    End If
                End If              

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Try
            Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\\result.txt")
            Dim finalresult As Integer = sr.ReadLine
            sr.Close()
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your Score is : " & finalresult & "');</script>")
            Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\\result.txt")
            sw.WriteLine(0)
            sw.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This code uses a technique that is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You need to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your Page_Load event selects all of the questions from tblQuestions, then puts the first one on the screen, then inserts that row into the database and then removes the value from the screen.  That logic is guaranteed to create duplicates of the first row, every time you load the page.  (because of the insert command)

Guessing: I think you probably want your Insert query to go in your button_click event handler (probably btnSubmit_Click).

Comment: So, this is part of a homework assignment?  It looks like you have most of the code, but it is just not arranged into the right code-blocks (event handlers).  I would recommend that you start by thinking about what you want to do logically, build an outline (I sometimes start with pseudocode on a whiteboard or paper), and then organize your code to follow your plan.       Unfortunately, in your question (above) you didn't say what your program is supposed to do.  You only said what is wrong.  So I can't tell you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use easily solve your problem of code repetition through the use of for loops and for each loops while just incrementing an integer variable.As your code is pretty much the same. Also maybe you should think of using entity frameworks or LINQ to SQL as it really helps makes things easier. Finally not sure but do you really need everything to be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding of how ASP.Net works. You're trying to do some initialization in Page_Load as if it runs once when the user first visits your page and you don't need to run it again.

**Every time the user does anything on your page that posts back to the server, ASP.Net destroys all the data in your page class and starts you over with a brand new page class.**

This is just how it works. You're going to have to completely rethink how you've designed this.